# shareThis share count API not updating in Ajax

Tags: ajax, sharethis

I'm using ShareThis's Share Count API Javascript call repeatedly on a page to get share counts for each story listed on the page. In my <head> I have:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'MY PUB KEY',onhover:false, newOrZero:"zero"});</script>

and in the body, at each instance of a story link ([storyID] is a unique multi-digit number):

<span id="shareCount[storyID]"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">stButtons.getCount("story URL","sharethis",document.getElementById('shareCount[same storyID]'));</script>

When the page loads, the API call runs and the share counts come in fine. But then, that portion of the page with the story listings get updated periodically with Ajax. Once again the API call runs and returns counts, but they are the same counts returned when the page first loaded, they have not been updated to match the actual count on each story.

The Ajax replaces an entire block of HTML. If the stButtons.getCount() function were not running, it would return no counts at all.

Anyone have any ideas why or how to overcome?